# PHP random folder

Tags: php, html, directory

Let's say I have the following directory tree

```
tmp
 ---cat
 ---dog
 ---mouse
```

My index.php is in the same directory  as `tmp` folder. How would I use PHP to save a random folder name as a variable? I've tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles(){
    $dir = './tmp';
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $randomFolder = '';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            $randomFolder = $randomFolder + $ff;
        }
    }
        echo $randomFolder;
    echo '</ol>';
}
listFolderFiles();
?>
```

Comment: Why are you echoing an `</ol>` when nothing else in the function outputs any HTML, including the starting tag?

Comment: $randomFolder = $randomFolder + $ff; should be $randomFolder = $randomFolder.$ff; OR $randomFolder = $ff;

Comment: This will certainly _not_ create a _random_ folder name. Why don't you use the functions php provides for such task?

Comment: And what is the plus sign doing in there? `$randomFolder + $ff`? `$randomFolder` and `$ff` are both _strings_.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of python when doing `$randomFolder + $ff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution can be the built in [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/de/class.directoryiterator.php) object for iterating through file systems. Just have a look at the following example.

```
$results = [];
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot() && $fileinfo->isDir()) {
        $results[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}
```

The given code iterates through a given directory and gives back all directories included in the given directory except the dots.

Answer (score 0):

By create, do you mean return/echo?

I don't think your function will produce a random folder. It will return the last folder.

```
function listFolderFiles(){
  $dir = './tmp';
  $Ignore = array('.','..'); // build an ignore array
  $Results = array();
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  foreach($ffs as $ff){
      if(!in_array($ff,$Ignore) && is_dir("./tmp/".$ff)){ // if filename is folder and not in ignore array
          $Results[] = $ff; // add filename to results
      }
  }
  shuffle($Results); // shuffle/randomize the results
  echo $Results[0];
}
listFolderFiles();
```